# Commenting out matched string and add new line after in bash script

Tags: linux, command-line, bash, sed, awk

I am trying to comment out a matched string in a file and add new line right below the matched string. Is there any way to do this ? May be using sed or awk.

For example,

```
line1 is good
line2 is bad
line3 is to be commented
line4 is final
```

I want to match line3 here (not using line number) and comment it out and add new line right below it.

**Expected output**

```
line1 is good
line2 is bad
#line3 is to be commented
new line
line4 is final
```

Answer (score 4):

Output to console:

```
sed '/^line3/s/^\(.*\)$/#\1\n/' testdata.txt
```

Replace in file and create backup:

```
sed -i.bak '/^line3/s/^\(.*\)$/#\1\n/' testdata.txt
```

Replace in file:

```
sed -i '/^line3/s/^\(.*\)$/#\1\n/' testdata.txt
```

Explanation:

General syntax for sed:

```
/pattern/action
```

Pattern is `^line3` (replace it with your pattern)

Action is `s/^\(.*\)$/#\1\n/`

**s** - sed replace command (s/pattern1/pattern2/)

**^(.*)$** - RegEx pattern to match all line

**#\1\n** - replace line with: hash (#) +  RegEx back reference (\1) + new line (\n)

Remember to:

- add backslash before parentheses
- surround all line with parentheses

Comment: Thanks. But can you please tell me the command for the expected output I ve mentioned so that I ll get a better idea.

Comment: @Unnikrishnan I've added 3 scenarios.

Comment: I mean the syntax to replace the "line 3" with new line commenting other

Comment: @Unnikrishnan Pleas explain. My solution works fine on Your example data